# Libreoffice cannot be started at runtime in php

Tags: php, laravel, pdf, libreoffice

I have installed `LibreOffice` version 6 at my `64 bit Windows 7 OS`.
If I try to convert `.docx` to `.pdf` from `Command Prompt`, it just works fine. But if I try to execute the command from `laravel`, it reports that the application cannot be started.

**Laravel Code**

```
$process = new Process('"C:\Program Files\LibreOffice\program\soffice.exe" --headless "-env:UserInstallation=file:///tmp/LibreOffice_Conversion_${USER}" -convert-to pdf --outdir D:\converted\ D:\acceptance.docx');

$process->run();
```

**Error Message**

[image: libreoffice error dialog]

There is any solution for this..?

Comment: Is the mentioned INI file accessible from Laravel?

Comment: how do i find it is accesible from laravel..?

Comment: You might like to run any other program instead of LibreOffice and let it open that file, in example Editor.

Comment: sorry i can't understand..

Comment: You have the constructor of the process for LibreOffice. Replace it for example with this: `new Process('C:\Windows\notepad.exe "C:\Program Files\LibreOffice\program\bootstrap.ini"');`

Comment: Did you check that the file `bootstrap.ini` exists?

Comment: yes the `boostrap.ini` file exists and also the `bootstrap.ini` file is opened in notepad using your code.     `Process('C:\Windows\notepad.exe "C:\Program Files\LibreOffice\program\bootstrap.ini"');`

Comment: Well, then it is time to visit the web sites of Laravel and LibreOffice and take a deep look, I would say. You might consider to create an account in their forums and ask there. You problem seem not to be in your program, but in the used applications.

Comment: now i am downgraded the libreoffice version to 4.0., but now the following error showing  `Fatal Python error: Failed to initialize Windows random API (CryptoGen)`

Answer (score 0):

That error is very confusing as it happens not only when `bootstrap.ini` file is invalid on disk but also when `-env` variables are incorrectly overridden while calling `soffice.exe`. Because LibreOffice verifies the content of `bootstrap.ini` file after the env vars are overridden at run time in memory.
`THANK YOU LIBREOFFICE FOR SUCH A MISLEADING ERROR` LOL.

I faced the same error at some point and did a little bit of investigation until I noticed the value I was setting for `-env:UserInstallation` was not correct.
In your case an argument is passed to the `Process` initializer which is as follows:

```
'"C:\Program Files\LibreOffice\program\soffice.exe" --headless "-env:UserInstallation=file:///tmp/LibreOffice_Conversion_${USER}" -convert-to pdf --outdir D:\converted\ D:\acceptance.docx'
```

and it looks like `${USER}` meant to be an environment variable. It may help if you test `Process` with a hard coded path. And to achieve that you can change `"-env:UserInstallation=..."` bit to
`-env:UserInstallation=file:///C:/tmp/LibreOffice_Conversion_abc`. Notice I've also added the drive `C:` letter in the path as your OS is Windows. Make sure this path exists and give it a test. If it works then you can focus on getting the argument right in the way you'd like it to work.

Please also have a look at the following page to get `file URI scheme` right for both Windows and Linux/Unix if you haven't already: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File_URI_scheme